# Server-client chat program - VMware on the same machine

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcpclient

I'm trying to create a server-client chat program in c for Linux.

Considering I only have one computer (a power house at that) I'm trying to create it so I can talk to a server with vitual machines running ubuntu. The host OS is windows 10.

I have booted up two different vitual machines with ubuntu (using VMware) and set the network connection to be bridged.

I have the server program working, sorta, in that it connects to a socket (5000) and listens to wait for a client to connect.

On the client I run the client and it never seems to connect to the host and I'm not sure why. I'm not sure if I need to specify the IP address or port number or what (I'm totally new to this). This is supposed to be a TCP connection that works will work within all machines within the subnet.

Here is what I have for the server:

[Server-chat.c](https://gist.github.com/ochinski/bd5a59bc88a98784bf273bed4cd70a29)

Here is what I have for the client:

[client-chat.c](https://gist.github.com/ochinski/72d2c31fee2e42ebd76107284e4c9c07)

After I run the server I get to the listen part.

I switch to the client running VM and run my client program "./client-chat 127.0.0.1"

assuming that's what I need for it to connect but apparently not. Any direction or resources would be much loved.

Comment: Your host OS and your virtual machine will have different IP addresses; 127.0.0.1 would only work if both your client and your server were running on the same machine (i.e. both in the host or both in the VM).  If you want your client (running in the VM) to connect to your server (running in the host OS), you'll need to specify a non-loopback IP address of the host OS rather than 127.0.0.1 (which, on the VM, refers to the VM itself)

Comment: This is fairly useless: *"... assuming that's what I need for it to connect but apparently not."* Perhaps you should state an exact error message from one of the calls you are using.